# Doing popups correctly

Tags: javascript, popup

Basically I have a website that offers a help system. When activated this help system triggers a popup in which the help content appears.

As the users then navigates around the site, through the use of a cookie I detect (that I set when the window is first opened and clear when the user closes the window) whether the window is still opened and load new help content for the new page.

As it turns out the only way to load new content into this popup window is to pop open a new page with the same name (so that we don't multiple popups opening everywhere) with the desired content.

This works fine the first time the user triggers the popup, but after that when I try and automatically try and pop open a window, I have problems with most browsers.

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I can get this to work correctly?'

*UPDATE*
@Rob

Here is that I have:

Page1.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MainPopup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Page 1</h1>
<a href="Page2.html">Next</a>
<a href="javascript:setPopupActiveCookie();popup('Help1.html')">Click</a>
<script type="text/javascript">popupWindowIfCookieSet('Help1.html');</script>
</body>
```

Page2.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MainPopup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Page 2</h1>
<a href="Page1.html">Prev</a>
<a href="javascript:setPopupActiveCookie();popup('Help2.html')">Click</a>
<script type="text/javascript">popupWindowIfCookieSet('Help2.html');</script>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Help1.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Helper.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Help 1</h1> 
</body>
</html>
```

Help2.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Helper.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Help 2</h1> 
</body>
</html>
```

MainPopup.js

```
var windowLocation;
 function setHelperWindow(new_windowLocation){
     windowLocation = new_windowLocation;
 }
 function popup(url){
     try{
         windowLocation.href = url;
     } catch(e){
         windowLocation = window.open(url, "HelperWindow").location;
     }
 }
 function popupWindowIfCookieSet() {
     //Stuffhere 
 }
 function setPopupActiveCookie() {
     //Stuffhere 
 }
```

Helper.js

```
(function(){
     var failures = 10*60; //Cancel poller after 1 minute without `opener`
     var poller = setInterval(function(){
        try{
            // Attempt to send the current location object to window.opener
            window.opener.setHelperWindow(location);
        }catch(e){
            if(!window.opener && failures-- < 0) clearInterval(poller);
        }
     }, 100);
 })();
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. What should happen is that if i pop open the Helper page from Page1, when I then go to Page2.html, the popup window showing the Help1.html content would switch to Help2.html.

Currently its not doing this. Any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

If your whole website is hosted at the same domain, you can use the `window.opener` property, in conjunction with some adjustments at your page.

1. Main: Declare a variable `windowLocation`, and functions `setHelperWindow` and `popup`
2. Main-popup: Open a new window, and store a reference in variable `windowLocation`
3. Helper-window: Create a poller, which attempts to invoke the `setHelperWindow` of the `window.opener` object. If the `window.opener` window has closed, the poller will terminate.

Because the `windowLocation` variable is getting updated all the time (either after using `window.open()` or by the poller function in the popup), the possibility of getting blocked by a popup blocker is reduced severely.

*Note: Both scripts has to be included at each main and helper page:

      `<script src="filename.js"></script>`*

#### Helper.js

```
 (function(){
     var failures = 10*60; //Cancel poller after 1 minute without `opener`
     var poller = setInterval(function(){
        try{
            // Attempt to send the current location object to window.opener
            window.opener.setHelperWindow(location);
        }catch(e){
            if(!window.opener && failures-- < 0) clearInterval(poller);
        }
     }, 100);
 })();
```

#### MainPopup.js

```
 var windowLocation;
 function setHelperWindow(new_windowLocation){
     windowLocation = new_windowLocation;
 }
 function popup(url){
     try{
         windowLocation.href = url;
     } catch(e){
         windowLocation = window.open(url, "HelperWindow").location;
     }
 }
```

#### Example: Usage (main)

```
<a href="javascript:popup('/help-pages/howto-doing-popups-correctly')">Click</a>
```

Comment: I think that will only work for him if he stays on the same page. Unless his site is driven purely by ajax he's going to lose the value of winHelper when he navigates to a different page.

Comment: Exactly. As soon as I navigate away from the window, I loose the context.

Comment: @TonyLeeper @vdh_ant See my updated answer. I've created a more reliable solution, which combines the best of `window.open(url,"name")` and my newly introduced `window.opener`.

Comment: @Rob updated question above with my attempt at trying what you have here.

Comment: @vdh_ant My current method involves one active main page, in conjunction with one pop-up. When the contents of that specific main page changes, the popup will still be accessible by the main page in the *same "main"* window.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a name for the window like you have done should work, e.g.

```
window.open('help1.html', 'help');
```

Then, e.g. when page2 loads,

```
$(function () {
    window.open('help2.html', 'help');
});
```

Bear in mind though that **the popup blocker is going to stop this behaviour from working** unless you add an exception.  E.g. in chrome, options >> under the bonnet >> content settings >> pop-ups >> manage exceptions.

Disclaimer: I'm not a fan of using popups and would use a **lightsout box** instead for your online help, loading the content via an **ajax** request.

Comment: I agree about what you are saying for the lightbox, but the experience the users want is to have the help in one window and navigate around in another window.

Comment: @vdh Well, as I said it should work using the above, but I suspect your problems are related to the popup blocker. Try adding an exception for your site to always allow popups. Gl.