# How pass window handler from one page to another? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have a very strange problem , please don’t ask me why do I need this…
I have a page1. Page1 has a link which opens new window (page2) using  window.open function.
chatWindow is a handler of child window with returns from window.open function.
Now I'm moving from page1 to page3 (by link `<a href="...." target="_self">Some Text</a>`). And I need to check on the page3 if page2 is close or open.
How to pass handler chatWindow from page1 to page3?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page2 and page3, you can refer to page1 using `window.opener`. In page1, you can define a method which checks whether page2 is still open or not: `window.open` returns an instance of the new window, and `null` if the window has been closed.

Note that you can only read properties from windows if they're at the same domain. If they're from different domains, you can enable communication using the [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) method.

Assuming that they're at the same domain, you can use the following code (concept code):

```
window.page2 = window.open('...');
window.page3 = window.open('...');

// At page3:
if (window.opener && window.opener.page2 != null) { // Not null or undefined
    // Do something
}
```

I have used global variables for the ease. A better implementation can consist of a namespace:

```
window.openedWin = {};
window.openedWin.page2 = window.open('...');
...
// At page3:
if (window.opener && window.opener.openedWin && window.opener.openedWin.page2 ...
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for the quake response. The problem that I'm losing page1 when moving to page3....

Comment: @DioNNiS That's a different problem. You can add a poller to `page2`, which periodically reports their presence to `page1` (and `page3`). This can be done by using `setInterval(function(){window.opener.page2=window;}, 1000);`, for example. Also report when the window is closed: `window.onunload=function(){window.opener.page2=null;};`. A similar question has been asked before, to which I [responded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7704292/938089?doing-pupups-correctly).

Comment: Yes, it looks like, that this is the only suitable solution